# Modify font of single element in forestplot

Tags: r, list, r-forestplot

I'm trying to modify make a single element in labeltext italics without making the entire column italics, with no luck. The following code will make the 1 italics:

```
library(forestplot)
```

## Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package

```
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
structure(list(
mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 
0.731)),
.Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
 c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
 "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
"Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
 c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
"4", "14", "3", "1", 
"8", NA, NA),
c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
"11", "20", "7", "7", 
"10", NA, NA),
c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
"0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
"1.02", NA, "0.53"))

 forestplot(tabletext, 
 txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = list(gpar(fontface = 3),
                                     gpar(fontface = 1,
                                          )),
                        ticks = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex=1),
                        xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySerif", cex = 1.5)),
       rbind(HRQoL$Sweden),
       col=clrs,
       xlab="EQ-5D index")
```

But how do I modify the script to only make "Male vs Female" italics (i.e. element 1,1 of label text).

More details on the function can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/forestplot.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is only support to style individual columns with the `fpTxtGp` for this at the moment but you can do a hack that gives you the same result if you don't have any summary elements in your table (from the vignette):

```
forestplot(tabletext, 
           boxsize = .05,
           is.summary=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(summary = list(
             gpar(fontfamily = "HersheyScript", fontface=1), 
             gpar(fontface=1)
             )
           ),
           rbind(HRQoL$Sweden),
           col=clrs,
           fn.ci_sum=function(col, size, ...) {
             fpDrawNormalCI(clr.line = col, clr.marker = col, size=.05, ...)
           },
           xlab="EQ-5D index")
```

[image: Forestplot output]

Comment: Thank-you for the response. This is very helpful. Similar question - is there a way to add superscript to a text column? I.e. a pval column written as 10 x 5^(-05) [where "-05" is superscript]. Thanks.

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how. It's part of the base system