# Making single element bold in forestplot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I want to make certain text elements bold in my forestplot column text. This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588972/modify-font-of-single-element-in-forestplot), but slightly different because I only want one item bolded.

Using a combination of `expression(bold())` I have been able to do so:

```
library(forestplot)
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017), 
    lower = c(NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365),
    upper = c(NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
    class = "data.frame")
tabletext <- cbind(
  c("Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch"),
  c("Deaths", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8"),
  c("OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02"))
tabletext_lists <- list(list(), list(), list())
        tabletext_lists[[1]] <- tabletext[,1]
        tabletext_lists[[2]] <- tabletext[,2]
        tabletext_lists[[3]] <- tabletext[,3]
        tabletext_lists[[3]][3] <- list(expression(bold("0.16")))
        tabletext_lists[[3]][7] <- list(expression(bold(tabletext_lists[[3]][7])))

forestplot(tabletext_lists,
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           clip = c(0.1,2.5),
           xlog = TRUE,
           col = fpColors(box = c(rep("royalblue", 5), "red", "red"),
                          line = "darkblue"))
```

Which yields this figure:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to make the item of interest appear bold without manually entering it in such as `tabletext_lists[[3]][3] <- list(expression(bold("0.16")))`

Is there a way to make individual elements bold without using the `is.summary` parameter from forestplot? And as such is it possible to do so without having to manually enter the text value itself and do so by slicing or normal selection from a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in forestplot the `txt_gp` option. List1 is a 2-dimensionnal matrix where `list[[row]][[column]]` is a `gpar(fontface="bold")` or `gpar(fontface="plain")`.
In the forestplot, it will put as bold or plain the element of interest.

For instance, in your case, `list1[[1]][[1]]` is for the element Auckland and should be set as plain.

```
forestplot(tabletext, 
         txt_gp=(label=fpTxtGp(list1))
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a little bit more in detail? I don't get, how your code fits to OP's code. And where in your code do you set `"plain"`.